# How to use Modals with input in react hooks

Tags: reactjs, laravel, modal-dialog

I'm new in react, using it in laravel application and i had written it with classes. now I'm trying to reformat code with hooks and cant realize how to reformat my modals. here is modal component:

```
const NewQuestionModal = ({isOpen, close, titleValue, solutionValue, onAddQuestion, onTitleChange, onSolutionChange  }) => {
    return(<Modal isOpen={isOpen} toggle={close}>
        <ModalHeader toggle={close}>Add a new question</ModalHeader>
        <ModalBody>

            <FormGroup>
                <Label for="title">Question</Label>
                <Input id="title"
                       value={titleValue}
                       onChange={onTitleChange}
                >sda</Input>
            </FormGroup>

            <FormGroup>
                <Label for="solution">Solution</Label>
                <Input id="solution"
                       value={solutionValue}
                       onChange={onSolutionChange}
                >sda</Input>
            </FormGroup>

        </ModalBody>
        <ModalFooter>
            <Button color="primary" onClick={onAddQuestion}>Add question</Button>{' '}
            <Button color="secondary" onClick={close}>Cancel</Button>
        </ModalFooter>
    </Modal>)
}

export default NewQuestionModal;
```

and I'm using it in main component like this:

```
 <Button color="primary" onClick={this.toggleNewQuestionModal.bind(this)}>Add question</Button>

                <NewQuestionModal
                    isOpen={this.state.newQuestionModal}
                    close={this.toggleNewQuestionModal.bind(this)}
                    titleValue={this.state.newQuestionData.title}
                    onTitleChange={(e) => {
                        let {newQuestionData} = this.state
                        newQuestionData.title = e.target.value
                        this.setState({newQuestionData} )
                    }}
                    solutionValue={this.state.newQuestionData.solution}
                    onSolutionChange={(e) => {
                        let {newQuestionData} = this.state
                        newQuestionData.solution = e.target.value
                        this.setState({newQuestionData} )
                    }}
                    onAddQuestion={this.addQuestion.bind(this)}
                />
```

Now I have states and appreciate any advice how to reformat my modals.

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to re-write the main component with hooks you don't need all of the this/bind references.  Here is an example of the main component with just the isOpen state:

```
const MainComponent = () => {
  const [newQuestionModalIsOpen, setNewQuestionModalIsOpen] = useState(false)

  const toggleNewQuestionModal = () => {
    setNewQuestionModalIsOpen(prevState => !prevState)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Button onClick={toggleNewQuestionModal}>Add Question</Button>
      <NewQuestionModal
        isOpen={newQuestionModalIsOpen}
      />
    </>
  )
}
```

Hopefully this gives you an idea how you can pass through the other props too.